# Define gpio in device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree, texas-instruments

I have a Ti's AM335x custom board. I want to define some pins as gpios and be able to set them as input and output in its Linux userspace.
I defined pins in `am33xx_pinmux` and then referenced it with the `bone-pinmux-helper`. The problem is I can set it with these commands on the terminal but it doesn't work.

```
echo 4 > /sys/class/gpios/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpios/gpio4/direction
echo 1 > /sys/class/gpios/value
```

here is a brief of my code for just two pins `gpio0_4` `gpio0_5`, each pin must become available to set as input or output in userspace.

```
#include "am33xx.dtsi"
#include <dt-bindings/interrupt-controller/irq.h>
&am33xx_pinmux {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    DATA_OUT_A00:DATA_OUT_A00 {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <0x158  (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE7) >;  /*gpio0_4*/
    };
    DATA_OUT_A01:DATA_OUT_A01 {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <0x15C  (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE7) >;  /*gpio0_5*/
    };
    ...
}

...

&ocp {
    test_helper: helper {
        compatible = "bone-pinmux-helper";
        status = "okay";
        pinctrl-names = "DATA_OUT_A00", "DATA_OUT_A01";
        pinctrl-0 = <&DATA_OUT_A00>;
        pinctrl-1 = <&DATA_OUT_A01>;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:-------------------**

I'm using main Ti kernel 4.9 version. If I want to define these two pins as output this DTS works fine but ONLY for output mode. I can export pins as input but when I read its value it always returns zero.

```
#include "am33xx.dtsi"
#include <dt-bindings/interrupt-controller/irq.h>


/ {
  model = "My Custom board C335x";
    compatible = "ti,am33xx";

    cpus {
        cpu@0 {
            cpu0-supply = <&vdd_core>;
        };
    };
  ...


  gpio-leds {
        compatible = "gpio-leds";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&led_pins>;
      // the following two blocks make the pins available in /sys/class/leds
      // if removed can be accessd with /sys/class/gpios
      test_led1 {
        label = "test";
        gpios = <&gpio0 4 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        default-state = "off";
      };
      test_led2 {
        label = "test";
        gpios = <&gpio0 4 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        default-state = "off";
      };
        };
  
}


&am33xx_pinmux {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
  led_pins: pinmux_led_pins {
        pinctrl-single,pins = <
            0x158   (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE7)   /*gpio0_4*/
            0x15C   (PIN_OUTPUT_PULLDOWN | MUX_MODE7)   /*gpio0_5*/
        >;
    };
  ...
}
```

If I leave these pins in the DTS file, I still can export them but I can't get any input or set a value as output to them.

Comment: What kernel version are you using?  Your DT makes no sense.  The pinctrl assignment is typically used for pin multiplexing, not for assigning GPIO.  Assigning a pin to a driver (as a multiplexed pin or as an assigned GPIO), ***excludes*** that pin from the sysfs GPIO interface.  The pinmux-helper device may allow you to use a sysfs device interface.  *"The problem is I can set it with these commands on terminal but it didn't work."* -- That's contradictory.  When the commands do not work, it's illogical  to claim that you *"can set it with these commands"*, since that implies success.

Comment: @sawdust Thanks. I'm using kernel 4.9. If I exclude all pins from DTS file. I can export each pin without a problem but when I set the value I see no output on pins I edit the code and add another code. And when I say it didn't work, I meant that I can set each pin and write a value to it but I see no difference. please check my second DTS file.

Comment: FYI sysfs gpio is deprecated and replaced with the character device ABI since version 4.8.  But GPIO from userspace is simply inferior method to use.  Your 2nd DT uses the leds-gpio driver, which is a recommended way of using GPIO (i.e. kernel driver).  But what sysfs interface are you using?  Are you using the **/sys/class/leds/** interface?

Comment: Ok, but I was looking for a way to define each pin for both input and output, If I define a pin with the led driver I cant make that pin as an input.
With above method, pins can be exported with `/sys/class/gpios` but if I create a sub node (I've added it to above DTS), the pins become available in `/sys/class/leds`. Both ways do the trick for me but if I make a pin as an input, what should I do?

Comment: Have you studied the [Linux kernel documentation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/Documentation/gpio), e.g. [Documentation/gpio/drivers-on-gpio.txt](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9/source/Documentation/gpio/drivers-on-gpio.txt)?

Comment: I read these docs. So It seems that each pin should only be OUTPUT or INPUT, not both. And if a pin is an output it should be referred to `gpio-leds` driver and if it is input it should be `gpio-keys`.Is it right?

Comment: *"So It seems that each pin should only be OUTPUT or INPUT, not both."* -- Correct.  *"Is it right?"* -- Yes.